# Outlook new message does not work after switching to office365

Tags: email, delphi, outlook, ole

We have the following function in our application which opens a new message in outlook so the user can send an email via Outlook.

```
program SO_37131815;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, ActiveX, ComObj, Variants, SysUtils;

procedure OutlookMail(ToAddress, Subject: string);
var
  OutlookProgram: OLEVariant;
  MailItem: Variant;
begin
  try
    OutlookProgram := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    OutlookProgram := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;

  MailItem := OutlookProgram.CreateItem(0);

  if ToAddress = '' then begin
    ToAddress := ' ';
  end;
  MailItem.Recipients.Add(ToAddress);
  MailItem.Subject := Subject;

  try
    MailItem.Display(False); //.Display(Modal)
  except
    //don't worry...
  end;

  OutlookProgram := Unassigned;
end;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  OutlookMail('', 'blah');
end.
```

[image: it's all greek to me]

This worked fine for years...since a couple of days ago when the client switched to Office365.
When a new message is created from outlook it works fine, when it's created from our application it cannot send the message.

In outlook 2010 the error message is: 
**"Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid."**

In outlook 2016 the error message is: 
**"Sorry something went wrong. You may want to try again"**.
[image: outlook 2016 error]

I also noticed that when the new message is created from our application it cannot be saved to drafts and it throws the same errors.

The procedure opens the new message window but when Send Mail is pressed, Outlook cannot send it.
What can I do, to fix this? Do I need to set some property before Display is called?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to David persistency I've narrowed it down. Outlook produces error when the ToAddress parameter is empty (or space).
So adding the following code seems to fix the problem.

```
if Trim(ToAddress) <> '' then begin
  MailItem.Recipients.Add(ToAddress);
end;
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]

Comment: Anyone with outlook (setup to work with office365) can copy-paste the procedure in a button and call it. I don't understand what else to do.

Comment: It would be less work if we had a complete program. We have to make sure we specify the necessary uses clause. A complete console app that we could paste would be less work for us, and we'd be sure that we were running the same code as you. Presumably you yourself have Office 365? And have you done any debugging? Which line of code leads to the error?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have edited the question to include the whole unit. The procedure opens the new message but when Send Mail is pressed outlook cannot send it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I took it one stage further to a complete program. We can now paste this and run it directly with no scope for confusion. If I were you I'd strip out code and see if you can identify a line without which the error does not occur.

Comment: At which point the error occurs? Does the message window of Outlook appears (MailItem.Display)? (BTW, MailItem should also be declared as OleVariant)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, see update

Comment: I'm not sure if you solved your problem or not. if `ToAddress` is empty why do you add `MailItem.Recipients.Add(ToAddress);`?

Comment: @kobik You are right, adding an empty address is what causes the problem with outlook. I 'll make another edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you want to write an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @kobik you also helped so i will give points to any answer you write too.

Comment: Looks to me like @kobik probably got there. I don't really want to write an answer and have it accepted. I'd say that others deserve it more. However, next time anybody whines at my asking for an MCVE, I'll just refer them to this question!  ;-)

Comment: @georstef, You can answer your own question. I only spotted the obvious but the conclusion was yours :)

Comment: @kobik you took the time to read the question and comment something helpful. I'd rather give the points to you than to answer it myself.

Comment: @georstef, OK. done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `ToAddress` argument is empty, You should not pass a space (or empty string) parameter to `MailItem.Recipients.Add` method.

So the solution is to avoid the above:

```
if Trim(ToAddress) <> '' then
  MailItem.Recipients.Add(ToAddress);
```